# OpenGL quadrilateral not being drawn

Tags: opengl, 3d, drawing

I am attempting to draw a quadrilateral (square) on the screen. I inserted this into a pre-existing program that drew a cylinder. This is in an orthographic modelview matrix, and I am almost positive the clipping volume is correct (It's 200 in any direction from the origin). In the display function I'm using, I pushed a matrix, translated forward (0.0,0.0,-20.0), called quadriliteral, and then popped the matrix. Are the any common openGL settings people use that I'm unaware of that may make this not visible? Is there a way to get the current clipping volume and print it out in the console?

```
void quadrilateral() 
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(0.5f,0.0f,0.8f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glVertex3f(-10.0f,-10.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-10.0f,10.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(10.0f,10.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(10.0f,-10.0f,0.0f);

    glEnd();
}


//This is called from a main function elsewhere
void draw(void)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500); 
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Cylinder");
    glutReshapeFunc(CChangeSize);
    glutSpecialFunc(CSpecialKeys);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Ckeyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(CRenderScene);
    CSetupRC();
    glPopMatrix();
}


void CSetupRC()
{
// Light values and coordinates
GLfloat  ambientLight[] = {0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
GLfloat  diffuseLight[] = {0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
GLfloat  specular[] = { 0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f};
GLfloat  lightPos[] = { -50.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f, 1.0f };
GLfloat  specref[] =  { 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 1.0f };


glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);    // Hidden surface removal
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);     // Do not calculate inside of solid object
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);

// Enable lighting
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

// Setup light 0
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT,ambientLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_AMBIENT,ambientLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,diffuseLight);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_SPECULAR,specular);

// Position and turn on the light
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,lightPos);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

// Enable color tracking
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

// Set Material properties to follow glColor values
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

// All materials hereafter have full specular reflectivity
// with a moderate shine
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR,specref);
glMateriali(GL_FRONT,GL_SHININESS,64);

// Black background
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );


glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

}


// Called to draw scene
void CRenderScene(void)
{
// Clear the window with current clearing color
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Save the matrix state
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();

// Rotate about x and y axes
glRotatef(CxRot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(CyRot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// Draw the cylinder
cylinder();

glPopMatrix();

// CylinderTwo
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();

// Rotate about x and y axes
glRotatef(CxRot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(CyRot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// Draw the cylinder
glRotatef(120.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
cylinderTwo();

glPopMatrix();

// Random square
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-30.0f,20.0f,10.0f);
quadrilateral();
glPopMatrix();

// Swap buffers
glutSwapBuffers();
```

}

Comment: Can you go ahead and post all of your relevant OpenGL initialization code? (look for the edit button on your post if you're not familiar with the site). There's about 100 different ways you can mess up, so it's probably best if we don't have to guess. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Sure thing, it's pretty long but I'll try to keep it short

Comment: Don't make it longer than it needs to be, but err on the side of oversharing if you don't know for sure if something is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your winding order is incorrect:

```
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

this line means it will cull back faces.

```
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
```

and this sets the front face to counter clockwise.

```
    glVertex3f(-10.0f,-10.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-10.0f,10.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(10.0f,10.0f,0.0f);
    glVertex3f(10.0f,-10.0f,0.0f);
```

Here you have clockwise ordering of your vertices meaning you are drawing with the back to camera.  either disable culling:

```
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

make the front face clockwise:

```
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
```

or change the order of your vertices to a counter clockwise order.

Comment: I tried all of the above, but alas, it still won't appear :( There must be something else is wrong too

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that your quad is wound backwards. You've enabled GL_CULL_FACE, which throws out any clockwise wound polygons, and your quad has a clockwise winding.

Either disable backface culling, or switch the order of your vertices to counter-clockwise.